# Auto-increment ID in shapefile table when adding new feature

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression

In QGIS I have a shapefile containing about 2000 features where I added a unique ID using the `$id` expression . I want to continue adding features to the same table, using the attribute feature pop-up after finishing the geometry creation.

My question is: is there an expression or function that auto-increment on the id numbers already in the id column? E.g. if you have id's from 1-2000, then QGIS automatically suggesting id number 2001 for the next feature added?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is [AutoFields](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/) plugin which does exactly what you have described.

[image]

After selecting the layer, choose your `id` field as the target **Existing Field** then give `$id` expression into the **Custom Expression**.

---

Having said that, I would recommend `Update existing field` in the Field Calculator.

[image]

It means you will update `id` field **after** adding features, but it would be easier.